# visual composer add custon raw js - WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-wordpress-pages, visual-composer

I want to create testimonial slider like this one https://codepen.io/pillotu/pen/weWzLE/ but it seems to be impossible to make its js work in the **visual composer** "raw js" content box.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //create the slider
 $('.cd-testimonials-wrapper').flexslider({
  selector: ".cd-testimonials > li",
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: true,
  slideshow: false,
  smoothHeight: true,
  start: function() {
   $('.cd-testimonials').children('li').css({
    'opacity': 1,
    'position': 'relative'
   });
  }
 });
});
```

I've tried many ways I saw in the internet, like using w3schools and jsfiddle, but nothing helped.

PLEASE HELP

[this is how my raw js box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMCak.png)

Comment: Could you be more clear about how it didn't work. For example is there any error appear in browser console?

Comment: No error message, no warning... it just wont work out. I save settings and when I apply to page, doesn't work.
If you have visual-composer at Wordpress, you can try this and I bet you will get the same issue.

Comment: Firstly, you can try to inspect your output html to make sure both html and js code exist (for example find the keyword cd-testimonials-wrapper). Secondly, in your case, I think implementing a custom shortcode is much better than embed code.